# Debugging libsass segfault in Ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, libsass

I took a working project under Ember CLI 0.1.15 and pushed it to 0.2.2 and started getting a segmentation fault. By installing [node-segfault-handler](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler) I was able to get some visibility into what was going on but not being very adept at reading these dumps I'm not taking much away from this other than it's clearly related to SASS compilation:

```
PID 30497 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x71
0   segfault-handler.node               0x00000001040f890f _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 287
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff90fd7f1a _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                                 0x000000010141c6a0 0x0 + 4316055200
3   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6fb3 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_expressionEv + 25
4   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6e11 _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_relationEv + 25
5   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6bd1 _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_conjunctionEv + 23
6   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6aef _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_disjunctionEv + 23
7   binding.node                        0x00000001078a27b1 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_space_listEv + 23
8   binding.node                        0x00000001078a2ccd _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_argumentEv + 349
9   binding.node                        0x00000001078a2a8a _ZN4Sass6Parser15parse_argumentsEv + 182
10  binding.node                        0x00000001078a8a30 _ZN4Sass6Parser19parse_function_callEv + 186
11  binding.node                        0x00000001078a7747 _ZN4Sass6Parser12parse_factorEv + 623
12  binding.node                        0x00000001078a714d _ZN4Sass6Parser10parse_termEv + 25
13  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6fb3 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_expressionEv + 25
14  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6e11 _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_relationEv + 25
15  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6bd1 _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_conjunctionEv + 23
16  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6aef _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_disjunctionEv + 23
17  binding.node                        0x00000001078a27b1 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_space_listEv + 23
18  binding.node                        0x00000001078a2ccd _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_argumentEv + 349
19  binding.node                        0x00000001078a2a8a _ZN4Sass6Parser15parse_argumentsEv + 182
20  binding.node                        0x000000010789de19 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_mixin_callEv + 211
21  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1949 _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 1103
22  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
23  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1cfb _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 2049
24  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
25  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1cfb _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 2049
26  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
27  binding.node                        0x000000010789b98b _ZN4Sass6Parser5parseEv + 1651
28  binding.node                        0x00000001078402c1 _ZN4Sass7Context10parse_fileEv + 375
29  binding.node                        0x00000001078c1a69 _Z16sass_parse_blockP12Sass_ContextPN4Sass7ContextE + 162
30  binding.node                        0x00000001078c144c _Z20sass_compile_contextP12Sass_ContextN4Sass7Context4DataE + 343
31  binding.node                        0x00000001078c1715 sass_compile_file_context + 487
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm using the **ember-cli-sass** addon (version 3.1.0) which works in other projects so i'm wondering how to proceed in debugging this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.